# Converting Shapefile to Autocad

Tags: shapefile, autocad

I am Trying to export from shapefile to autocad.
But it is not converted correctly.
My labels are not shown.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure if that is working with ArcMap. I just saw a presentation where they did that with Feature Manipulation Engine [FME](http://www.safe.com/), I don't know if there is any opensource software available.

Comment: Try to use Spatial Manager for AutoCAD: http://www.spatialmanager.com/spm-forautocad/ Autodesk Exchange: https://apps.autodesk.com/ACD/en/Detail/Index?id=appstore.exchange.autodesk.com%3aspatialmanagerforautocad_windows32and64%3aen