# Importing shapefile into AutoCAD?

Tags: shapefile, autocad

I am using autocad for students 2017; I have tried to use the compiled command, but it has not worked. Also, I have tried the command, Mapimport and AutoCad doesn't even found it.

How can I import a shapefile into AutoCad in order to get some measurements I'm interested with?

Comment: Have tried importing without command? If not this will help you. [Link](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/autocad-map-3d/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2017/ENU/MAP3D-Use/files/GUID-D65473F6-0B63-4F4E-A3B7-9B8EE8217B77-htm.html)

Comment: @BunnyChowdary, that link states that the workflow applies to AutoCAD Civil 3D 2017, AutoCAD Map 3D 2017, and AutoCAD Utility Design 2017.  Not AutoCAD for Students 2017.

Comment: I'm no CAD expert, but as far as I know only those mentioned by Fezter _can_ import shapefiles, and it might not be possible in "plain" AutoCAD. Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/182009/converting-shapefile-to-autocad?rq=1 (FME is the way to convert easily, not sure if there are student licenses available.)

Comment: I voted to reopen because this question is about **AutoCAD** and not about **AutoCAD Map 3D**. There will be two different answers for  **AutoCAD** and for **AutoCAD Map 3D**.

Comment: Haven't tried this online or portable https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/

Answer (score 4):

Plain **AutoCAD** has **no** command to open or import the geospatial vector data format shapefile.

The geospatial vector data format shapefile consists of a collection of files (*.shp, *.shx, *.dbf and other).

Beware of confusion: *AutoCAD* uses *.shp files for custom symbols. These *.shp files are also called shapefiles but are not the same as the geospatial vector data format shapefile. The AutoCAD command `compile` converts the *.shp to a *.shx file. But this *.shx file is used for custom symbols.

What other options are there?

- *AutoCAD Map 3D* and *AutoCAD Civil 3D* are able to open or import the geospatial vector data format shapefile. (The command `mapimport` can be used in *AutoCAD Map 3D* but not in plain *AutoCAD*)
- The plug-ini [Spatialmanager](http://www.spatialmanager.com) for AutoCAD imports shapefiles into *AutoCAD*.
- Use another software to convert shapefiles to dxf (e.g. QGIS, FME)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the ArcGIS [Export To CAD](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/manage-data/cad/exporting-features-to-cad-drawings.htm) tool to export your shapefiles to the DXF or DWG format first, and then import/use it in AutoCAD.

Answer (score 1):

This site will do it all for you:

https://mygeodata.cloud/converter/shp-to-dxf

Drop all 3 files ( .shp and .dbf and .shx) and it will convert to a .dxf file which can easily be opened in AutoCAD.